# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins Result while executing the test case from Git:

```
[[1;34mINFO[m]  T E S T S
[[1;34mINFO[m] -------------------------------------------------------
[[1;34mINFO[m] Running [1mTestSuite[m
SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mTests [0;1mrun: [0;1m24[m, [1;31mFailures: [0;1;31m1[m, Errors: 0, [1;33mSkipped: [0;1;33m23[m, Time elapsed: 2.329 s[1;31m <<< FAILURE![m -- in [1mTestSuite[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] org.testpackage.TC001_Signup.launch[org.testng.TestRunner@5e8f9e2d, chrome](0) -- Time elapsed: 1.630 s <<< FAILURE!
**org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'ip-10-1-1-111', ip: '10.1.1.111'**
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:541)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:237)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:73)
    at org.basepackage.VisionBaseClass.launch(VisionBaseClass.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:361)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:296)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:823)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:590)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:969)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:829)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:431)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:391)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:308)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.16.1', revision: '9b4c83354e'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2.0-1015-aws', java.version: '11.0.21'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:523)
    ... 43 more
```

This is about my Jenkins server

```
ubuntu@ip-vw-x-y-zzz:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

ubuntu@ip-vw-x-y-zzz:~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.21" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Webdriver and browser:

```
ubuntu@ip-vw-x-y-zzz:~$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 120.0.6099.224 (3587067cafd6f5b1e567380acb485d96e623ef39-refs/branch-heads/6099@{#1761})

ubuntu@ip-vw-x-y-zzz:~$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 120.0.6099.224
```

Web driver path:

```
ubuntu@ip-vw-x-y-zzz:~$ which chromedriver
/usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Browser path:

```
ubuntu@ip-vw-x-y-zzz:~$ which google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Java-Selenium code for browser startup:

```
 if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        // Set the path to the Chrome binary (not ChromeDriver)
        options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome");

        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

        // Set ChromeDriver system property with longer timeout
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");

        // Instantiate the ChromeDriver with the configured options
        setDriver(new ChromeDriver(options));
    }
```

Comment: As the message says *Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.* Have you checked if the IP is correct and reachable?

Comment: Kindly explain how do I Check the IP is correct and reachable?